# How i can set the background image of image?

Tags: html, css

I have a image who's width and height i got in Javascript. i want to set the background image on image.

means to the background image is look like image as youtube show the image on video called play icon.

i want to show them on image. can someone tell me how i can set playicon over the image.

Comment: if your using javascript why not just add the image (a .png with transparency) with z-index and absolute positioning and set the containing div / element with a position relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand exactly your question. I suppose you want to place `img` over a `background-image` if yes check the following example:

**html**

```
<div>
    <img id="play" src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/454/000&text=Play">
    <img id="pause" src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/848/000&text=Pause">
</div>
```

**css**

```
div {background:url("http://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff&text=video") no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
}
img#play {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;   
}
img#pause {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:40px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ACazB/

`div` has `position:relative` and `img`s inside `div` have `position:absolute`. This will allow you to manipulate the position of any images in the scope of `div`. Using box offsets `top`, `bottom`,`left`,`right` you can move the images in the place you need.

http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props